# --global option does not exist while doing a composer --global require

Tags: symfony, composer-php, drupal-8, drush

I'm trying to set up my work environment at home. I'm developing a drupal8 project and need to run with a vagrant. So far so good, installed of vagrant composer and php went well. Now I need to use drush to be able to rebuild my cache etc.

Here some more infos :

```
vagrant@lashootingboxd8:/var/www/drupalvm/drupal$ composer --version
Composer version 1.9.0 2019-08-02 20:55:32
```

```
vagrant@lashootingboxd8:/var/www/drupalvm/drupal$ composer --global require drush/drush
    1/1:        https://packages.drupal.org/8/drupal/provider-2019-3$3852c4e111957318dd45daf9d2d7b3ab725e924276f9288a039edfea6e7a8e56.json
    Finished: success: 1, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 1
    1/2:        http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-latest$febfbf81e3ff08dabc4f583cddc865afb94c4c6c978e23baa7372527f0cbdf3a.json
    2/2:        http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2019-07$b9d9f8cb7e5d9896a78be68dec5d2d9e7ec04a5e5cc4d500f799d4cb8af75e4a.json
    Finished: success: 2, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 2


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "--global" option does not exist
```

So if you guys have any idea of how to fix that would be awesome

EDIT : 
I did try the composer gloab require drush/drush, it doesn't give me an error but I still don't have anything as you can see below : (sorry I'm a very very noobie for this type of problem)
[image]

Comment: `Drush only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency.` Local dependency. See https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a `npm` or `yarn` package manager. In composer you have to use as, 
**`composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`**
There is nothing like `--global` in composer.

Another thing, **`drush`** installed properly but it couldn,t find PATH.run command `touch ~/. bash_profile` and then put `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/drush` in there. Save, close and reopen the terminal.

Comment: Yeah I did try it but forgot to post, I just edited my question

Comment: Seems you are running on a mac. your installation is installed properly. Close and reopen terminal once,  then try running `drush status` again. If it's still doesn't work, run command `touch ~/. bash_profile` and then put `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/drush` in there. Save, close and reopen terminal.

Comment: also, check your project dependency and run `composer install` once

Comment: I will try to do so, and no I'm under windows unfortunately for this week end

Comment: here is what I get when I'm running drush status directly in my folder with Cmder [link](https://imgur.com/oM21Cz0) yet it still doesn't work when I'm inside vscode

Comment: It's path issue, configure path, in windows environment variables.

Comment: Now I get this following [error](https://imgur.com/pOuaE2T), it will never end lol

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer global require drush/drush` There is no --global flag

Comment: Forgot to put it but I tried! See my edit on my post

Comment: It says that drush is needed locally in the project. Run `composer require drush/drush` from the drupal directory

Comment: it works when I do it this way see : [imgur](https://imgur.com/oM21Cz0)